# Why do propTypes live on the class but not other methods?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class

I read that using `static` for `propTypes` puts the it on the class instead of the instance of the React component. I don't get the difference between putting something on the class vs. the instance though. Why is `propTypes` on the class but not methods like `render` and `componentDidMount`, or other custom made methods inside the component?

Answer (score 1):

It's for the same reason as the keyword `static`. This is un-changing static metadata that helps describe your class. It can be accessed without needing to instantiate your class (accessed without calling the constructor).

```
class example extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        something: PropTypes.object,
    }

    static displayName = "ExampleDisplay";

    render() {
        return <div />;
    }
}

// I can access static properties here directly
var types = example.propTypes; 
var name = example.displayName;


// I can NOT access the render method without instantiating the class.
var instance = new example(); // <- this calls the constructor and creates an instance.
var renderFn = instance.render;
```

The question is really: why should I need to create the class just to read the propTypes or displayName? you shouldn't need to. that's why you have static.